# node/angular app - trouble with subscriptions/observables - how to limit what comes back on subscription

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs-observables

I am new to Node/angular and really am struggling to understand observables/subscriptions etc. I am working off of some existing code and am running into an issue that I want to understand how to solve.

I have a component which is a list of records, and within that component I run this function on button click:

```
deleteRecord(id) {
    this.recordService.delete(id);
    this.recordService.responseMessage$.subscribe(response => {
        if (response.message = 'record deleted') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:`Record ${id} deleted`});
        } else if (response.message = 'could not delete record') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Oops!', detail:`Not able to delete record.`});
        }
    });
}
```

The message service is from PrimeNg (angular framework) - and all it does is create a 'toast' message (green popup message) that the record was succesfully deleted. The problem I'm running into is that if I delete one record from the list, and then delete another, the second time I delete a record it will show two toast messages, rather than just the last one. If I keep deleting, it will keep adding to the amount of toast messages that it shows when I click delete. If I console.log the response within this function, I do see that every time I click delete, it adds another object to the response so I am sure this is why it is showing multiple toast messages. I simply want to know if/how I can limit it to only the last one I clicked - or understand how I can fix this otherwise.

The delete function in my record service looks like this:

```
...

export class RecordService {
    private responseMessageListener = new Subject<any>();
    responseMessage$ = this.responseMessageListener.asObservable();

...

    delete(id: number) {
        this.http.delete<{message:string}>(this.authService.getApiUrl(`/record/${id}`)).subscribe(response => {
            this.getRecords();  // this is so the list updates in the browser
            this.responseMessageListener.next(response);
        })
    }
}
```

the response message will either be 'record deleted' or 'could not delete record' based on if the SQL query is successful or not.

I also tried doing this a slightly different way, and it does seem to only show one toast at a time (although it never shows the first one), but if I console.log the response it is still showing multiple instances of a response if I click delete on more than one item on the list. This is the second way I tried ... though I think I would like to stick with the first example unless there are strong reasons why I shouldn't. I tried it this way so I can unsubscribe from the 'recordListenerSub', since I didn't know how to unsubscribe the first way.

```
private responseListenerSub: Subscription; // maybe delete

...
ngOnInit(): void {

    deleteRecord(id) {
      this.responseListenerSub = this.recordService.getResponseListener().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.response = response.message;
      });
      this.recordService.delete(id);
    
        if (this.response == 'recorddeleted') {
          this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:`Record ${id} deleted`});
        } 
        if (this.response == 'could not delete record') {
          this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Oops!', detail:`Not able to delete record ${id}.`});
        }
    }
}

...

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.responseListenerSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as intended. Right now every time you call `deleteRecord` method you are creating a new subscription which accumulate over time.

What you should do is to create one subscription in `constructor` or `ngOnInit` with your message handling logic.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.responseListenerSub = this.recordService.responseMessage$.subscribe(response => {
        if (response.message = 'record deleted') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:`Record ${id} deleted`});
        } else if (response.message = 'could not delete record') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Oops!', detail:`Not able to delete record.`});
        }
    });
}
```

In `deleteRecord` method you would only call your service `this.recordService.delete(id);`

Finally you should also unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` as you did in your example.

Answer (score 0):

When an observable is subscribed to, the subscription will remain active until it is either unsubscribed from or the observable completes.

In your case, every time the `deleteRecord()` method is called, a new subscription is being created. To prevent duplicate toast messages, the `responseMessage$` should complete after it emits. The easiest way to accomplish this is to augment your current method to use the [`first`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first) or [`take`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) operator. Both of these operators can be used to automatically complete the observable and close the subscription after the first value is emitted.

`first` operator:

```
deleteRecord(id) {
    this.recordService.delete(id);
    this.recordService.responseMessage$.pipe(
      first(),
    ).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.message = 'record deleted') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:`Record ${id} deleted`});
        } else if (response.message = 'could not delete record') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Oops!', detail:`Not able to delete record.`});
        }
    });
}
```

`take` operator:

```
deleteRecord(id) {
    this.recordService.delete(id);
    this.recordService.responseMessage$.pipe(
      take(1),
    ).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.message = 'record deleted') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:`Record ${id} deleted`});
        } else if (response.message = 'could not delete record') {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Oops!', detail:`Not able to delete record.`});
        }
    });
}
```